# Count the number of rows for records

Tags: postgresql

My data like

```html
report_id   report_number   event_id
"149317"    2               "3403"
"149315"    1               "3403"
"149314"    0               "3403"
"149320"    1               "3405"
"149319"    0               "3405"
"149327"    0               "3409"
```

Expected :

On the basis of event_id , adding a new column in result set to show the max report_number of that `event_id`

```html
report_id    report_number      event_id        count 
    "149317"    2               "3403"            2
    "149315"    1               "3403"            2
    "149314"    0               "3403"            2
    "149320"    1               "3405"            1
    "149319"    0               "3405"            1
    "149327"    0               "3409"            0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MAX` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT *, MAX(report_number) OVER (PARTITION BY event_id) count
FROM yourTable;
```